# Visual studio downloads and installs updates even when told not to

Tags: windows, visual-studio, download, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I am running Visual Studio 2019 Community Preview on Windows 10 Pro.

My network connection is set to "metered".
I have "Automatically download updates" checked off in VS update settings.
The VS extensions are set to automatically check for updates but not to install them.

Still, I visual Studio downloads tens of megabytes, in the Windows usage details for vs_installerservice.exe and VSIXInstaller.exe, as well as in the log files in the temp directory (dd_BackgroundDownload*, dd_service*, dd_setup*, etc.) which indicate components being downloaded and installed -- at times when VS was not running.

How do I prevent VS from doing unsolicited/unattended downloads and installs?
I want to have control over when downloads and updates happen without having to worry about data charges.

Comment: Are you sure that updates are being installed?  You mention "VS extensions are set to automatically check for updates.." which implies to me that some connectivity is needed in order to check if updates are needed - even if they are not downloaded or installed.

Comment: This could *possibly* be your Windows Update settings. In the "Advanced" settings, do you have "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows" set?

Comment: @PeterM, the log files contained lines about "downloading" and "installing" (unfortunately I cleaned my temp folder).

Comment: @AdrianMole, Yes, I do, but shouldn't it respect metered connections?